# Do we want to hold a major retagging event? / Das große Retaggen: ja oder nein?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Let’s face it: Many of our questions are poorly tagged.

One possibility to deal with this would be a major retagging event where we coordinate our efforts for one week or similar (e.g., along the upcoming [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)), to retag a big bunch of questions, e.g., to remove and replace unwanted or overused tags.

What changes exactly we want to pursue and how we do it would have to be decided in more detail later. Before we do this, we should however make clear whether we want this at all and how many people would participate.

Please state your stance (yes/no/I would/wouldn’t help) in answers or by voting upon existing answers. I intentionally didn’t create some standard answers to impose some threshold.

---

Die meisten unserer Fragen sind schlecht getaggt.

Eine Möglichkeit, dieses Problem anzugehen, wäre ein großes Retaggen, bei dem wir über eine Woche o. ä. (zum Beispiel während des bevorstehenden [Winter Bashs](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)) unsere Kräfte bündeln, um eine große Menge Fragen zu retaggen, um z. B. unliebsame oder übermäßig verwendete Tags zu entfernen und durch bessere zu ersetzen.

Bevor wir entscheiden, was genau wir ändern und wie das Ganze ablaufen wird, sollten wir erstmal klären, ob wir dies überhaupt wollen und wie viele Nutzer mithelfen würden.

Bitte tut Eure Einstellung hierzu (ja/nein/dabei/nicht dabei) in den Antworten kund. Ich habe absichtlich keine Musterantworten erstellt.

Answer (score 11):

Ganz ehrlich? Auf GSE "kratzen" mich die Tags wenig (Schande über mich...). Tags sind ein gutes Mittel, um auf anderen (z.B. technischen) SE-Sites Dinge auseinanderhalten zu können, die nun so genau gar nichts miteinander zu tun haben (z.B. C- und VBA-Fragen auf SO). Die meistverwendeten SO-tags beziehen sich auf eine Programmiersprache - Übertragen auf GSE würden wir nur ein Tag "Deutsch" brauchen, was zugegebenermassen ein bisschen sinnlos ist...

Sprache ist für mich ein wesentlich komplexer geknüpftes Netzwerk als diese "anderen Themen". Man kann oft z.B. Grammatik nicht getrennt von Bedeutung und Ethymologie oder Stil sehen - Ich bin bisher noch nie auch nur auf die Idee gekommen, z.B. nach Tags zu suchen oder nur bestimmte Tags zu beantworten,... Ich habe eher das Gefühl, dass Tags hier im Prinzip nur verwendet werden, weil SO "sie halt anbietet". Das ist aber dann nur purer Selbstzweck und ein Aufräumen Beschäftigungstherapie.

Das dürfte mit ein Grund sein, warum die Tags hier so "unaufgeräumt" aussehen, und aus dieser Sicht ist es wie gesagt auch einigermaßen unnötig,  aufzuräumen. Das Tag-System "passt" einfach nicht richtig auf natürliche Sprache.

Wenn ich ein bisschen mehr drüber nachdenke: Es gibt ein paar Tags, die ich wirklich für sehr sinnvoll halte, z.B. "false-friends" - Das kann ein Frager allerdings aus naheliegenden Gründen selten selbst setzen.

Trotzdem würde ich bei einer solchen Initiative natürlich im Rahmen meiner Möglichkeiten mithelfen. Mein Enthusiasmus dafür hält sich aber in Grenzen...

Answer (score 4):

Ich möchte eine partielle Gegenmeinung zu Tofro in den Raum stellen.

Wie man an meinem Meta-Post von vor einiger Zeit sieht, finde ich das korrekte Taggen »schon irgendwie« wichtig. Vieles ist schlecht getaggt, vieles müsste besser getaggt werden und einiges ließe sich dadurch besser finden, besser einordnen, usw. Unsere Fragen lassen sich meines Erachtens durchaus kategorisieren, wenn auch die Kategorisierungen nicht ganz so »klar« sind wie zum Beispiel auf Stack Overflow. Und richtig gesetzte Tags können uns Antwortern Hinweise geben, wie eine Fragestellerin ihre Frage meint.

Dennoch denke ich nicht, dass wir in einem gesammelt-gestemmten Kraftakt einen Tag-Weihnachtsputz machen müssen oder sollten. Wir sind eine recht kleine Seite, da ist es klüger, wenn man nebenher etwas macht. Gerade da unser Fragenvolumen relativ klein ist, würde eine große Menge Retagging-Edits die Fragenseite fluten, und alles andere viel zu sehr aus dem Blickfeld drängen.

Statt eines groß angelegten Events halte ich es für sinnvoller, wenn alle, die Fragen gerne besser getaggt sähen, sich täglich drei bis fünf Fragen vornehmen – und auch nur, wenn nicht zu viel andere alte Bewegung auf der Seite ist. Bei der Gelegenheit sollte auch gleich der Inhalt abgestaubt und aufgehübscht werden. Das bringt der Seite in meinen Augen mehr.